# Using FastText word embedding with sklearn SVM

Tags: python-3.x, svm, text-classification, fasttext

I'm trying to use fasttext word embeddings as input for a SVM for a text classification task. I averaged the word vectors over each sentence, and for each sentence I want to predict a certain class. But, when I simply try to use the vectors as input for the SVM, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

*some traceback stuff*

VallueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I suspect I have to convert the word embedding vectors into some other kind of format, but I'm not really sure what that would have to be. I find the documentation on sklearn confusing.

Does anyone know how to use the fasttext embedding vectors as input for a SVM?

Thanks in advance. If there is anything you need to know, let me know.

CptBaas

Comment: Showing the minimal code necessary to reproduce the error, and the full error stack (with traceback listing involved files/lines-of-code), would help potential answerers know what you're working with and what you've tried so far to hit the error.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I'm working on a protected virtual machine, so I had to type everything, since I'm not allowed to access the internet through it, so I hoped someone would be able to help me based on this minimal information.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be a list:

In python should be:

```
list(your_data)
```